# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: hibernate

Error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.myapp.struts.timesheetForm

The above error occurs when attempting to save data from a Bean within an Action class in Struts using the hibernate framework.

The main files:

```
timeSheet.jsp
timesheetForm.java
timeSheetAction.java
```

TimeSheetData.java is my pojo.

Extracting data from the database using hibernate is easy and works like a charm. timeSheet.jsp gets populated perfectly.

My timesheetaction.java is where I plan to save the updated data to the database.

I create a bean object based on the form data.

I create an object based on the timesheetdata.java

I use beanutils to copy the properties of the formbean into the pojo.

then update via the session object.

I have worked out that its null but thats as much as I can work out.

```
Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
sess.beginTransaction();
timesheetForm formBean = (timesheetForm)form;
timeSheetData formData = new TimeSheetData();
formBean.setAdditionhours4_1(formBean.getAdditionhours1_1());
BeanUtils.copyProperties(formData, formBean);
sess.update(formData);
sess.getTransaction().commit();
sess.flush();
sess.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    // extract user data
    timesheetForm formBean = (timesheetForm)form;

int count = 0;
   int loopConstraint = 0;

   while(loopConstraint < dataList.size())
   {

      int ID = Integer.parseInt(dataList.get(loopConstraint).toString());
      TimeSheetData formData = (TimeSheetData) sess.load(TimeSheetData.class, ID);

   //relevant additions to database

    sess.update(formData);
      sess.flush();
      sess.clear();

   }
      tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no records are available to update

Comment: i have 60 records in the db, the bean is working correctly as i have checked and it does pull data through/

Answer (score 0):

Please check you hibernate mapping, this problem can be easyly addressed by changing updatable and insertable params in anotations.

For example, in my case I solved it by changing it:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "columnPK", updatable = true, insertable = true)
private List<ObjectX> relatedElments;
```

with this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "columnPK", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private List<ObjectX> relatedElments;
```

The explanation is that this params prevent hibernate to update a related table while you try to insert/update other 'super' table. So, check all the hibernate anotations.